# How to get next sibling xpath using selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I Have following code where I am trying to download the csv file.

```
chromedriver = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#aggregated-data')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dashboard-tab-content-options-state']//div[@class='dashboard-tab-content-options-item' and text()='SA']").click()
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dashboard-tab-content-download-btn' and text()= 'Download Historic Data as .csv']")
button.click()
```

which select SA filed in first xpath as following,[image]

However I want to select the SA field from below options like following.
[image]

the html code as follows :-

```
<div id="dashADF" class="dashboard-tab-content" style="display: block;">
            <div class="dashboard-tab-content-row">
    <div class="dashboard-tab-content-options">
        <div class="dashboard-tab-content-text-container">
            <div class="dashboard-tab-content-title">Aggregated Price and Demand Data - Current Month</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard-tab-content-options-state">
            <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="true" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item active">QLD</div>
            <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="true" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">NSW</div>
            <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="true" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">VIC</div>
            <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="true" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">TAS</div>
            <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="true" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">SA</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dashboard-tab-content-row">
    <div class="dashboard-tab-content-download">
        <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="true" class="dashboard-tab-content-download-btn">Download Current Month</div>
    </div>
</div><hr>
<div class="dashboard-tab-content-row">
    <div class="dashboard-tab-content-options">
        <div class="dashboard-tab-content-text-container">
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="dashboard-tab-content-options-state">
                <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="false" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item active">QLD</div>
                <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="false" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">NSW</div>
                <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="false" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">VIC</div>
                <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="false" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">TAS</div>
                <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="false" class="dashboard-tab-content-options-item">SA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-tab-content-options-time">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dashboard-tab-content-row">
    <div class="dashboard-tab-content-download">
        <div data-tabname="dashADF" data-current="false" class="dashboard-tab-content-download-btn">Download Historic Data as .csv</div>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: please provide your respective html code of inspected element

Comment: dont use text()='SA' there are multiple of its

Comment: @AshishKamble you can directly visit https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#aggregated-data

Answer (score 1):

I would use this XPath

```
//div[.='Aggregated Price and Demand Data - Historical']/following::div[.='SA']
```

This will get you exactly the one you want. You can even throw this in a function and pass in the section name and button text and get any combination you want.

```
def click_button_in_section(section_name, button_text)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[.='{}']/following::div[.='{}']".format(section_name, button_text)))).click()
```

and then call it like

```
click_button_in_section("Aggregated Price and Demand Data - Historical", "SA")
click_button_in_section("Aggregated Price and Demand Data - Historical", "NSW")
click_button_in_section("Aggregated Price and Demand Data - Current Month", "TAS")
click_button_in_section("Aggregated Price and Demand Data - Current Month", "VIC")
```

... and so on

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the the **SA** *tab* within **Aggregated Price and Demand Data - Historical** section you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.aemo.com.au/Electricity/National-Electricity-Market-NEM/Data-dashboard#aggregated-data')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dashboard-tab-content' and @id='dashADF']//following::div[@class='dashboard-tab-content-options-item' and text()='SA'][2]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: second_SA]

Comment: Using indexes are dangerous because if the page changes, your locator may continue to work but click the wrong item... meaning you aren't testing the intended target. This may result in a hard to track down failure or pass and not be testing what you intended... both of which are not good(tm).

Answer (score -1):

both of elements looks same contains the same text inside tags,
i hope this will work try this,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-tabname='dashADF' and @data-current='false' and  text()='SA']");

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='TAS'])[2]/following::div[1]");

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Download Historic Data as .csv'])[1]/preceding::div[2]");

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='dashADF']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[5]");

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dashADF']/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]");
```

Comment: Using indexes are dangerous because if the page changes, your locator may continue to work but click the wrong item... meaning you aren't testing the intended target. This may result in a hard to track down failure or pass and not be testing what you intended... both of which are not good(tm).

Comment: @JeffC can you please modify my answer, so i could get to understand more about it.

Comment: When you use locators that have `div[3]` indexes in them, the HTML can change but your locator will still be looking at the 3rd DIV which means it's no longer looking at what you intended. So either your locator just breaks or you might be clicking the wrong button which is going to be really hard to track down... it may not even fail. See my answer for an alternative that doesn't use indexes and will move with the heading text.